# How to convert letters to numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, converters

I have been trying to create a simple javascript program where the user types in words/sentences, and the program shows the numbers you would enter to text it in a flip phone. For instance, if I entered "add" it would output "122".

How would I do this? I have tried a lot of different things, and nothing works. It seems like it should be a simple program. Can you either help me do this, or link me to a similar program?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Wouldn't a simple object with the letters as keys and numbers as values work?

Comment: `add` should map to `233`, the number `1` doesn't have letters mapped to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 function str2num(mystr) {
   mystr = mystr.toUpperCase();
   var conv = [];
   var l = mystr.length;
   for (var i=0; i conv[i] = mystr.charCodeAt(i)-65;
 }
   return conv;
 }
```

[Read this](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstrconv.htm)

http://www.yaldex.com/FSEquivalents/PhoneNumberConverter.htm for phone converter

in case the link breaks here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

<!-- Begin
 function convert(input) {
 var inputlength = input.length;
 input = input.toLowerCase();
 var phonenumber = "";
 for (i = 0; i < inputlength; i++) {
 var character = input.charAt(i);

 switch(character) {
 case '0': phonenumber+="0";break;
 case '1': phonenumber+="1";break;
 case '2': phonenumber+="2";break;
 case '3': phonenumber+="3";break;
 case '4': phonenumber+="4";break;
 case '5': phonenumber+="5";break;
 case '6': phonenumber+="6";break;
 case '7': phonenumber+="7";break;
 case '8': phonenumber+="8";break;
 case '9': phonenumber+="9";break;
 case '-': phonenumber+="-";break;
 case  'a': case 'b': case 'c': phonenumber+="2";break;
 case  'd': case 'e': case 'f': phonenumber+="3";break;
 case  'g': case 'h': case 'i': phonenumber+="4";break;
 case  'j': case 'k': case 'l': phonenumber+="5";break;
 case  'm': case 'n': case 'o': phonenumber+="6";break;
 case  'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': phonenumber+="7";break;
 case  't': case 'u': case 'v': phonenumber+="8";break;
 case  'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': phonenumber+="9";break;
}
}
document.myform.number.value = phonenumber;
return true;
}
//  End -->
</script>
<form name=myform>
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td>Alphanumeric #:</td>
<td><input type=text size=20 maxlength=20 name=alphabet value="Rachel"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Converted #:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=20 maxlength=20 name="number"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center colspan=2><input type=button value="Convert" onClick="return    convert(document.myform.alphabet.value)"></td>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: The OP is looking to map the letters to numbers 1-9, like how they are mapped on a phone.

Comment: Thanks so much - though is there anyway to just go like a=1, b=1, c=1, d-2, etc.? Would I list them as characters or variables? How would I set up the function?

Comment: you could look at this either http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp it might be better

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why 65 equals A though

Comment: Ah thanks. Wait, but if I did "var n = String.fromCharCode(65);" would that convert characters to numbers, or the other way around? Also, would iI put that in a function?

Comment: @CallaCarter please accept by clicking the tick beside the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qbFxs/1/

```
var map = [' ',,'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqrs','tuv','wxyz'];

$("#input").keyup(function(e){
    var v = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        out = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++){
            if (map[j] && map[j].indexOf(v[i]) > -1){
                out.push(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $("#output").text(out.join(''));
});
```

**Note:** I mapped space to `0`, you can get rid of the first element in the map array if you don't want this.

Comment: Thnks so much - is there some sort of a submit button?

Comment: Wiat, I see how itworks. Thanks so much for this - how can I get it into Komodo Edit? For some reason it doesn ot work when i put it in Komodo edit...

Comment: True, well thanks a lot for all you did do - mucly appreciated