# Listing valid words from phone mapping

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I recently came back from an interview and they asked basically: Given a list of valid words and a mapping of numbers to letters - something like 1 -> ABC, 2->DEF - how would I write a function that returns a list of strings that are valid. I struggled really hard and am looking for guidance.

```
function validWords(digits, listOfValidWords) {

}

// for example
var dictionary = [//some list of words];
var words = validWords("1456", dictionary)
```

Comment: Is 1456 is a one number or 4 separate numbers or any combination of these numbers can be a result? Like 1, 4, 5, 6, 14, 15, 16, etc.

Comment: Typed number keys on the phone. For instance, the key "1" can mean "A" or "B" or "C".

Comment: fill your `dictionary` with sample values and post the expected result

Comment: A regular expression would probably be the easiest...`1456` could map to `/[abc][jkl][mno][pqrs]/`, then just iterate through the list looking for matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert letters to numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818204/how-to-convert-letters-to-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) seems to be a sensible approach, especially if the number of valid words is not too big .

Comment: Here it is in C ;) http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=9

Comment: I would note that the interviewer is looking for your ability to problem solve. They do not want just the ability to simply regurgitate found code. You need to start by breaking the problem down into it's technical component parts based on the business case that you were given. You need to be able to recognize common patterns in what is asked for, etc. Make sure you understand not just what the solution is, but also the route by which you reach it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination algorithm.

```js
var dictionary = { 2: 'abc', 3: 'def', 4: 'ghi', 5: 'jkl', 6: 'mno', 7: 'pqrs', 8: 'tuv', 9: 'wxyz' },
    number = '345',
    result = [...number]
        .map(n => [...dictionary[n]])
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => v + w)), []));
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution (functional approach).